# C# After changing Generic to Async , How to resolve this error ? Task<T>

Tags: c#, generics, task

I used this Extention with Await Task command.

```
public static async Task<T> GetCompletedTask<T>(this T command) where T : CommandBase
    {
        var tcs = command.GetTaskCompletionSource();
        await tcs.Task.ConfigureAwait(false);
        return command;
    }
```

Here is example to use.

```
var result = await Class.GoRun(1).GetCompletedTask();
```

Method "GoRun" made by a Generic.

```
public T GoRun<T>(int RunnderID)
        where T : CommandBase
```

....

but I have to change the "GoRun" to async...
because I want to use await in GoRun. then I change like this.

```
public async Task<T> GoRun<T>(int RunnderID)
        where T : CommandBase
```

....

after this modification. "GetCompletedTask" generate error.

**How should I modify  it (GetCompletedTask) ?**

Here is error message.( I translated from Japanese to English )

```
'System.Threading.Tasks.Task<Bg7Uwp1.Commands.Device.SerialConnectCommand>' can not use T in a generic type or method 'CommandExtensions.GetCompletedTask<T>(T)' There is NO "Implicit reference conversion"
From 'System.Threading.Tasks.Task<Bg7Uwp1.Commands.Device.SerialConnectCommand>' to 'Bg7Uwp1.Commands.CommandBase'
Bg7Uwp1
```

in my idea, I have to modify "getCompletedTask". I wrote a bit.. but no idea...

[image]

Comment: _"After changing Genereic to Async"_? o_O

Comment: What error does it generate?

Comment: What title is better ? I tried best.. .... (^_^;

Comment: Why are using async in GoRun ? as you are already calling GetCompletedTask with await

Comment: in the generic function "GoRun", I must use "await _semaphores.WaitAsync();" to lock a hardware resource. This change GoRun to "public async Task<T> GoRun<T>(int RunnderID)
        where T : CommandBase"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the little bit of code you have shared, you would need to change your call site to `await` both the `GoRun()` method and the `GetCompletedTask()` method:

```
var result = await (await Class.GoRun(1)).GetCompletedTask();
```

That is, first you need to await the result of `GoRun(1)`, and then you need to pass that result to the `GetCompletedTask()`, which you also await.

Now, will this do what you want? I don't know. You don't have enough code in your question, never mind a good [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable code example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that fully illustrates your scenario. If the above doesn't solve your problem satisfactorily, please improve your question.